# Prevent scroll wheel from being able to scroll div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've got two divs beside one another. Both are equal heights and can be scrolled.

```
<div class="timerowlabels">
</div>
<div class="teamtimematrix">
</div>
```

I've then got js so that when .teamtimematrix is scrolls, .timerowlabels will also be scrolled along with it. This works well.

```
 $('.teamtimematrix').on('scroll', function () {
    $('.timerowlabels').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
});
```

When the user hovers over timerowlabels and uses their scroll wheel, I don't want anything to happen (i.e. I don't want them to be able to scroll up or down on timerowlabels). How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$('.timerowlabels').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (e) { return false; });